# Facebook conversion tracking values for predetermined events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Can the *{value: '0.00'}* parameter be used with all 9 predetermined Facebook events for conversion tracking? For example, I am trying to say that a Search is worth 2.30. This is not a monetary value however, so I was leaving out the currency. Will this show up in Facebook's system?

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '924082587688070');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'Search', {value: '2.30'});
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=924082587688070&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Have you tried this with already? What was the result of this test?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have read, this is valid for all the facebook standard events. If you do not supply a currency I am pretty sure facebook will use the currency you have registered for you account.